# Claim-augmented market is arbitrage-free

Tags: finance-mathematics, portfolio, pricing, asset-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory

Suppose we have a no-arbitrage market with a risk-free rate $r$ and $d$ risky assets with prices $(S_t)_{t \in \{0,1\}}$. Let's introduce a claim with payout $Y$, and assume that there exists a price $\pi = y$ such that the augmented market also has no arbitrage. Now consider a market where the initial price of the claim is $\pi = y - \frac{1}{n}$. How might we show that there exists a portfolio $(\theta_n^T, \phi_n)^T$ such that

$$\theta_n^T[S_1 - (1 + r)S_0] + \phi_n[Y - (1 + r)(y - \frac{1}{n})] \geq 0$$

almost surely? How would we show $\phi_n > 0$?

I know that under a risk-neutral measure $Q$, $E^Q[S_1] = S_0(1 + r)$, and $E^Q[Y] = \pi(1 + r)$. I also know that the portfolio's value at time 1 is $\theta_n^T S_1 + \phi_n (1 + r) = Y$ by the replication principle. But how do we use these equations to get the inequality above? Any help would be appreciated!

Is it true that under $\mathbb{Q}$, the expected return of the present value of the portfolio equals the initial price adjusted for the risk-free rate, so $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[\theta_n^{\top} S_1 + \phi_n (1 + r)] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y] = \pi(1 + r)$?